# Nested conversation list with django

Tags: python, django, list, foreign-keys, nested

Hay I have a model like this

```
def Photo(models.Model):
    # Photo object fields...

def PhotoThread(models.Model):
    photo = models.ForeignKey(Photo)
    message = models.TextField(blank=True)
    reply_to = models.ForeignKey('self', related_name='replies', null=True, blank=True)
    votes = models.IntegerField()
```

As you can see a Thread object has a reply_to field, so that Threads can become children of other Threads.

I can do stuff like -

```
photo = Photo.objects.get(pk=1)
threads = photo.photothread_set.all()
```

This will get the threads to a Photo, however, this system allows replies to also have replies.

How would i go about looping through all replies and getting replies for those (all the way down to the maxiumum number of replies we have).

I want to display this as a nested HTML list. Also i want to be able to order all Threads and replies by the 'votes' field.

Thanks

Comment: There are several ways to build such a list.  Please provide an example list that shows precisely what structure you want.

Comment: Update your question, please.  Don't add comments.  Fix the question.

Comment: Depending on the size of your threads, this approach might be quite slow. Check out django-mptt for a more efficient way to handle trees with Django http://code.google.com/p/django-mptt/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write an inclusion template tag that uses itself in its template.

Comment: Nope. But it's really not terribly hard. Just do a `{% load %}` at the top of the template and pass on through `replies` for the current message.

Comment: Okies, i got you. I'll have a go at writing a custom templatetag.

Comment: Im struggling to get this working, have you got a sample to get me started?

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to recursion.  Here's a common solution

```
def thread_plus_replies( someThread ):
    return someThread, [ thread_plus_replies(r) for r in someThread.replies.ordered('votes').all() ]
```

This kind of thing returns a list of 2-tuples for each thread and all of it's replies.

If a reply has no subsidiary threads, the follow-on list is empty.  This can get clunky, so some folks like to optimize it.

```
def thread_plus_replies( someThread ):
    if len(someThread.replies) == 0:
        return someThread
    return someThread, [ thread_plus_replies(r) for r in someThread.replies ]
```

Sticking with the first one, each thread is a 2-tuple.  We can decorate the 2-tuple with HTML.

```
def make_html( thread_results ):
    head, tail = thread_results
    return "<ul><li>{0}</li><li>{1}</li></ul>".format( head, make_html(tail) )
```

This will give you nested `<ul>` tags for your nested threads.

Comment: Where should this code go? Within the model as a method? or as a templatetag?

Comment: and is thread_results within the third function a result from Thread.objects.all() ?

Comment: @dotty: "Where should this code go?"  View functions.  "thread_results within the third function a result from Thread.objects.all() ?".  No.  Not even close.  It's the results of `thread_plus_replies`: a two-tuple of thread and replies to that thread.

Comment: This is what I've got http://pastie.org/1326181 however its throwing a 'function' object has no attribute 'replies' any ideas?

Comment: I've updated my question with a real representation of my models.

Comment: @dotty: "a 'function' object has no attribute 'replies'"  Right.   Your model says 'reply_to'.  Yet, my examples use 'replies'.  Interestingly, you have to do some **thinking** to match my answer against your newer (and changing) model.  It's okay to think.  It's better than copy-and-paste.  Really.

Comment: okies, i actually went with Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams method of writing a template filter, i got it to work surprisingly well. Thanks for the answer though, taught me about python format function.