# Django template iterate over nested lists

Tags: python, django, django-templates

In Django, how do we iterate over lists in template for something like `[[1,[2,[3]],[4,[]]],[2,[3]]]`.

Please note that the above is just a random example. Each element of list can have any number of nested lists further inside. I would like to iterate through each and every value inside and also have an idea of what is the parent so that we can appropriately style the HTML.

Although there is one way to generate HTML in the view itself by recursion and use the corresponding variable in template, this makes the django template and view dependent which is not desired([loose coupling principle](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/misc/design-philosophies/#loose-coupling)). One example of using views is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4277243/nested-conversation-list-with-django) but a representation in template system itself would be better than this type of implementation.

Comment: It sounds like you should be using [`mptt`](http://django-mptt.github.io/django-mptt/).

Comment: I agree with Burhan. https://github.com/django-mptt/django-mptt/ Not only provides the tree modeling structure, but also very handy template tags to recursively render portions of templates.

Comment: Does this mean that implementing directly in templates without touching databases and apps is not possible or desirable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django template is not designed to handle complex logics.
For example, you ***can't*** write nested logic by using `include` tag like this:

```
# foo.html
{% if nodes|iterable %}
<ul>
{% for x in nodes %}
  {% include "foo.html" with nodes=x %}
{% endfor %}
</ul>
{% else %}
<li>{{ nodes }}</li>
{% endif %}
```

Because Django template nodes get parsed and compiled before they get rendered, and the compiling of the above code could fall into loops and fail by hitting maximum recursion depth.

Normally, a template tag just like `{% nested nodes %}`, which works like a view but belongs to the scope of Django template, is all you need.

Moreover, you could transform the data to a flat one through a filter, then loop over it easily:

```
{% for x in nodes|nested_to_flat %}
{% if x.start_nodes %}<ul>{% endif %}
{% if x.end_nodes %}</ul>{% endif %}
{% if x.start_node %}<li>{% endif %}
{% if x.end_node %}</li>{% endif %}
{% if x.is_data %}{{ x.data }}{% endif %}
{% endfor %}

# nested_to_flat
@register.filter
def nested_to_flat(nodes):
    if isinstance(nodes, list):
        yield {'start_nodes': True}
        for node in nodes:
            yield {'start_node': True}
            for i in nested_to_flat(node):
                yield i
            yield {'end_node': True}
        yield {'end_nodes': True}
    else:
        yield {'data': nodes, 'is_data': True}
```

This is similar to the idea of rendering a mptt tree or threaded comments.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the above comments [django-mptt](https://github.com/django-mptt/django-mptt/) is a premade solution, which should fit your problem quite good.

If you want to roll you own template tags, you can have a look at [custom template tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/) in the django documentation.

Some hints:

- By creating markup with unlimited nesting you might run into usability problems because screen real estate is limited and probably want to consider limiting the depth of the data structure for this reason. If you have to stick with your data structure, you can use for loops in the template according to the number of levels.
- If you prefer the built-in template tags, you will be much better of using a list of nested dictionaries (containing lists wherever order is important), which also will be easier to read in the template.
- Loose coupling is fine as a general principle. But as the views main purpose in Django is to prepare the data structure for the template, you can't decouple it totally.